# git create master branch from develop

Tags: git

Background:
When I joined this company, the company used GitHub as it's source control. All development was done on the "develop" branch and I'm not even sure if a "master" branch formally existed. Shortly after joining, we switched to VSTS (now Azure DevOps) Git. We created a new Repo and changed remotes from GitHub to the new Git Repo and pushed develop. This was great, we got all of our history and source code. The new VSTS Git repo has a "master" branch, but is not related to our "develop" branch at all.

Now:
Our Dev manager left and with him left the requirement of single branch development (*relief*). But now I am stuck. The goal is a strategy like [nvie](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). I have tried PR'ing into "master" but this always results in merge conflicts which can not be resolved by merging master into dev and then PR'ing (as I am use to). I suspect that this is because "develop" was not created as a branch from "master". How can I retro-actively fix this? I'd like to keep all the develop commit history.

I was thinking about renaming develop -> master and then creating a new master, but will this break all the feature branches which are not yet PR'd?

Comment: If you never used `master`, why don't you simply remove master (on VSTS) and then create a new `master` from `develop`?

Comment: Too soon to tell, but it looks like this solved it. Thanks. Feel free to add as answer and I'll mark it after our next release.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the different [merge strategies of git](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge).

There is the `ours` strategy - `git merge -S ours develop` - that will merge in the develop branch while ignoring all the changes in the `develop` branch. So will end up with a branch that looks like before but from now on acts as a true descendant of `develop` allowing further merges to only introduce new changes committed after the first merge.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at this great read. I have learned a lot more about merge strategies now. But, what is unclear, will I have to then do an "ours" merge everytime now? I'd really like to fix the issue of master and develop not sharing a common ancestor.